# Eclipse RCP Plug-in Target Platform

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP project that I currently develop under Eclipse Indigo and platform 3.7.

I want to re-create this project under Luna (4.4). When I create new plug-ins, on the New Plug-in Project page, under Target Platform, my choices for "This plug-in is targeted to run with Eclipse version" are limited to 3.5 or greater, 3.4, 3.3, 3.2, and 3.1.

Why do I not see 4.4? Or even 3.7? I downloaded and am using the the Luna 4.4 with RCP. From Vogella, I also installed the e4 tooling (0.17).

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. '3.5 or greater' covers all later versions of Eclipse. Only the Eclipse releases where something changed in the plugin architecture are shown.